# Implementing write-preferring R/W lock

Tags: locking, mutex, readwritelock, rwlock

I have a mutex library, and am trying to implement a write-preferring lock.
I am looking at this example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock

I understand the read-preferring lock, but I don't understand the write-preferring lock. Can someone explain how to implement that?

Specifically, I don't understand this part:

```
While w:
  wait c, m
```

I also don't understand if the flag `w` is universal, or just a different flag per process. I assume it's the former.

For example, here we see the algorithm for getting a read-lock:

```
Lock m (blocking).
While (w or r > 0):
  wait c, m
Set w to true.
Unlock m.
```

but what does `wait c, m` mean?
It can't mean waiting to get a lock on both `c` and `m`, because we already locked `m` in step 1.

And also, for `Set w to true` - does that mean `w` has to be set to true in all processes or just this process?

Comment: I translated the wikipedia article write-preferring lock to here: https://github.com/ORESoftware/live-mutex/blob/dev/docs/write-preferring-rw-lock.md

Comment: Given my translation, another thing that confuses me is that it seems like every operation has to get a lock on m. That means that readers will block readers which is not that ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article referenced in your question [has a subscript note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock#cite_ref-10) that states:

`This is the standard "wait" operation on condition variables, which, among other actions, releases the mutex m.`

[Standard "wait"](https://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/teaching/3420ICT/cgi-bin/man.cgi?pthread_cond_wait) on conditional variable functions typically accept two parameters: a conditional variable and a mutex. The mutex `m` is released by the "wait" function and the [thread sleeps until `c` is signaled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522858/understanding-of-pthread-cond-wait-and-pthread-cond-signal). The `m` lock is re-acquired (which could involve waiting if a lock has been acquired elsewhere) once `c` is signaled and the thread proceeds.

Setting the (global) flag `w` to true indicates a write lock is currently claimed by a write thread.

Mutex `m` is locked only while negotiating the [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) of setting or releasing read/write states by modifying condition variable `c`, integer `r` (number of readers waiting), flag `w` (writer waiting).

The pseudo-code you posted for acquiring a read-lock (which is actually getting a write-lock, thus the `Set w to true`) uses both a mutex (`m`) and a [conditional variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables) (`c`). First, it attempts to attain an exclusive lock on the mutex `m` in order to modify the relevant inputs in an atomic fashion. Once this is achieved, it calls `wait c, m` if `w` (write lock) or `r` (readers waiting) are non-zero.

To summarize:

- the "wait" function accepts two parameters: `c` and `m`. It releases `m` and sleeps until receiving a signal on `c`.
- the mutex `m` is locked when setting or releasing a read- or write-lock.